# Google OAuth ,Error 401 invalid client

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-data-api, oauth2-playground

I am trying to login using **google+** .But getting

> 401. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.
>   Request Details
>
> ```
>         access_type=offline
>         openid.realm=
>         scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
>         origin=http://localhost
>         response_type=code permission
>         redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/localhost?id=auth929840
>         ss_domain=http://localhost
>         client_id={{ CLIENT_ID }}
> ```

I have double-checked the client id .Help would be appreciated
I have attached my `index.php` file.

```
         <?php
        /*


    * Sample application for Google+ client to server authentication.
     * Remember to fill in the OAuth 2.0 client id and client secret,
     * which can be obtained from the Google Developer Console at
     * https://code.google.com/apis/console
     *
     * Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    /*
     * Note (Gerwin Sturm):
     * Include path is still necessary despite autoloading because of the require_once in the libary
     * Client library should be fixed to have correct relative paths
     * e.g. require_once '../Google/Model.php'; instead of require_once 'Google/Model.php';
     */
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ .'/vendor/google/apiclient/src');

    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    /**
     * Simple server to demonstrate how to use Google+ Sign-In and make a request
     * via your own server.
     *
     * @author silvano@google.com (Silvano Luciani)
     */

    /**
     * Replace this with the client ID you got from the Google APIs console.
     */
    const CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX-itqqmr9qhegol91ne7sgkkeksmncfgqp.apps.googleusercontent.com';

    /**
     * Replace this with the client secret you got from the Google APIs console.
     */
    const CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';

    /**
     * Optionally replace this with your application's name.
     */
    const APPLICATION_NAME = "CoachGator";

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');

    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

    $app = new Silex\Application();
    $app['debug'] = true;

    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
        'twig.path' => __DIR__,
    ));
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

    // Initialize a session for the current user, and render index.html.
    $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        $state = md5(rand());
        $app['session']->set('state', $state);
        return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
            'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
            'STATE' => $state,
            'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
        ));
    });

    // Upgrade given auth code to token, and store it in the session.
    // POST body of request should be the authorization code.
    // Example URI: /connect?state=...&gplus_id=...
    $app->post('/connect', function (Request $request) use ($app, $client) {
        $token = $app['session']->get('token');

        if (empty($token)) {
            // Ensure that this is no request forgery going on, and that the user
            // sending us this connect request is the user that was supposed to.
            if ($request->get('state') != ($app['session']->get('state'))) {
                return new Response('Invalid state parameter', 401);
            }

            // Normally the state would be a one-time use token, however in our
            // simple case, we want a user to be able to connect and disconnect
            // without reloading the page.  Thus, for demonstration, we don't
            // implement this best practice.
            //$app['session']->set('state', '');

            $code = $request->getContent();
            // Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
            $client->authenticate($code);
            $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

            // You can read the Google user ID in the ID token.
            // "sub" represents the ID token subscriber which in our case
            // is the user ID. This sample does not use the user ID.
            $attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($token->id_token, CLIENT_ID)
                ->getAttributes();
            $gplus_id = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];

            // Store the token in the session for later use.
            $app['session']->set('token', json_encode($token));
            $response = 'Successfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);
        } else {
            $response = 'Already connected';
        }

        return new Response($response, 200);
    });

    // Get list of people user has shared with this app.
    $app->get('/people', function () use ($app, $client, $plus) {
        $token = $app['session']->get('token');

        if (empty($token)) {
            return new Response('Unauthorized request', 401);
        }

        $client->setAccessToken($token);
        $people = $plus->people->listPeople('me', 'visible', array());

        /*
         * Note (Gerwin Sturm):
         * $app->json($people) ignores the $people->items not returning this array
         * Probably needs to be fixed in the Client Library
         * items isn't listed as public property in Google_Service_Plus_Person
         * Using ->toSimpleObject for now to get a JSON-convertible object
         */
        return $app->json($people->toSimpleObject());
    });

    // Revoke current user's token and reset their session.
    $app->post('/disconnect', function () use ($app, $client) {
        $token = json_decode($app['session']->get('token'))->access_token;
        $client->revokeToken($token);
        // Remove the credentials from the user's session.
        $app['session']->set('token', '');
        return new Response('Successfully disconnected', 200);
    });

    $app->run();
```

Comment: You shouldn't make your client ID visible on any public site.

Comment: make sure to have Google+ API enabled